# How can i parse specific data from XML via simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I am facing the following XML:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_PURCHASE_VALUTA
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-14 13:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 17.0266
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.326
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.4771
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 26.0743
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 19.5504
                        )

                )
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_DEVIZA
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-14 13:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 18.1262
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.6161
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.7017
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 27.5739
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 20.813
                        )

                )
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_PURCHASE_DEVIZA
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-14 13:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 17.34581
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.46043
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.54232
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 26.46609
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 19.91697
                        )

                )


        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_MIDDLE
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-14 13:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 17.736
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.53827
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.622
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 27.02
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 20.365
                        )

                )

        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_VALUTA
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-12 00:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 18.3578
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.6435
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.7488
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 27.8306
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 21.0322
                        )

                )
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_PURCHASE_VALUTA
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-12 00:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 17.0275
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.3251
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.4771
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 26.0743
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 19.5082
                        )

                )
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_DEVIZA
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-12 00:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 18.1272
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.6152
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.7017
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 27.5739
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 20.7681
                        )

                )
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_PURCHASE_DEVIZA
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-12 00:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 17.34679
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.45955
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.54232
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 26.46609
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 19.87394
                        )

                )
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_MIDDLE
            [valid_from] => 2015-12-12 00:00:00.0
        )

    [currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => AUD
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 17.737
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => HRK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.53737
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DKK
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 3.622
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => EUR
                            [quota] => 1
                            [rate] => 27.02
                        )

                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => JPY
                            [quota] => 100
                            [rate] => 20.321
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am not fimilar with XML at all. I have always used JSON. I need to return 2 arrays from the XML. the must listen to specific conditions.
I need only the `[currency]` array where the type is valid from today. like

```
[valid_from] => date('Y-m-d')
```

Online URL to the XML:

[Link here](http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/f1afed)

I need two arrays one:

```
@type:XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_PURCHASE_DEVIZA
@valid_from:2015-12-12 00:00:00.0
```

And

```
@type:XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_DEVIZA
@valid_from:2015-12-12 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: sort of a hack and not always the best idea, but if you are more comfortable with JSON (or a native array) you can do `$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_file($path));` to convert it to a native array you can then `json_decode($json, true)` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead `DomDocument` - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

it allows you to read xml and select its nodes

```
// Example
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML( file_get_contents($path) ); // $path -> where your xml saved

// it has methods get element by tag name       
$tag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("some_tag_name");// it will return array
// it has methods get element attributees
$tag->item(0)->getAttribute('some_attribute'); // you can take 0 index and read its attribute 
// to take tag value you can
$tag->item(0)->item(0)->nodeValue
// ...
```

If this basic example is not enough, if you can post your xml in your uestion i can try to help you with creation of exact commands

**UPDATE**

```
$currencyArr1 = array();
$currencyArr2 = array();
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML( file_get_contents('http://104.236.115.118/application/currency_values/RB_Exchange_list.xml') );//$path path to your xml

$exchangeRates = $dom->getElementsByTagName("exchange_rate");

foreach ($exchangeRates as $exchangeRate){

    $validFrom = $exchangeRate->getAttribute('valid_from');// Your date
    $type = $exchangeRate->getAttribute('type');// Your type

    //First array case
    //@type:XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_PURCHASE_DEVIZA
    //@valid_from:2015-12-12 00:00:00.0
    if( $type == "XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_PURCHASE_DEVIZA" && 
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($validFrom)) == date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2015-12-12 00:00:00")) ){

        $currencyes = $exchangeRate->getElementsByTagName("currency");

        foreach ($currencyes as $currency){
            $currencyArr1[] = array(
                    "name" => $currency->getAttribute("name"),
                    "quota" => $currency->getAttribute("quota"),
                    "rate" => $currency->getAttribute("rate"),
            );
        }
    }

    //Second array case
    //@type:XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_DEVIZA
    //@valid_from:2015-12-12 00:00:00
    if( $type == "XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_DEVIZA" && 
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($validFrom)) == date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2015-12-12 00:00:00")) ){

        $currencyes = $exchangeRate->getElementsByTagName("currency");

        foreach ($currencyes as $currency){
            $currencyArr2[] = array(
                    "name" => $currency->getAttribute("name"),
                    "quota" => $currency->getAttribute("quota"),
                    "rate" => $currency->getAttribute("rate"),
            );
        }
    }
}

echo "ARRAY1:"; var_dump($currencyArr1);
echo "<br /><br />ARRAY2:"; var_dump($currencyArr2);
```

Comment: I have added a link to the XML, so you can see it. and the conditions I need. hope you can help! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help. i am getting: array(0) { }

Comment: I did few updates, i was in hurry and did not test last part it should work now, but make sure that you have in your xml records with `valid_from="2015-12-14 00:00:00.0"` and `type="XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_PURCHASE_DEVIZA"` date according to your conditions in question

Comment: Still null array. i also fixed the $type == "XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_VALUTA" && it was only one equal sign. not sure what's going on

Comment: Ok try once again to copy past my exact code i fixed there also `$type ==` and other `attribute` selections part, make sure you have such tag in your xml `<exchange_rate type="XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_VALUTA"
  valid_from="2015-12-14 00:00:00.0">`

Comment: Here you can see the output: array(0) http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/99wz-n16b straight from the dumping the exchangeRates. however this works fine: $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('book.xml');
echo $doc->saveXML();

Comment: Check the new code above after **UPDATE** and place it in your  `phpfiddle` it will work as you need

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4zs0-citr - if you will need customize it take attention on conditions `$type ==`  and `date's` comparations

Comment: The problem was that we tried to get currency of today 00:00 which still doesn't exists... hah Thanks for saving the day @Armen!

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in using SimpleXML, you should use the [`xpath` function](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

For example, this should theoretically let you iterate through all of the elements named "exchange_rate" with `type=XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_VALUTA`

```
$content->xpath('exchange_rate[type="XML_RATE_TYPE_EBNK_SALE_VALUTA"]');
```

You can then loop through the result and compare the values of different attributes (found through the [`attribute` property](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)).